# R plotly - line plot with only two dates forces the plot to be intraday

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2020-12-11","2020-12-11","2020-12-12"),
                 typ=c("shirts","sweaters","sweaters")
                 sold=c(644,3032,407), check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

All I need is simply a line plot inside my shiny application. This is how I build the plot:

```
line_text <- paste0("PORT ID: ",df2$typ)
plt <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~sold, color = ~Action, connectgaps = TRUE, mode = "lines+markers", 
                 text = line_text) %>% add_lines() %>% layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Now, if I leave the code as is, the x-axis will show as x lables values like "00:00 Dec 11, 2020".
Why?
[image]

One thing I tried to adjust it is the following:

```
plt <- plt %>%
    layout(
      #title = "Time Series with Custom Date-Time Format",
      xaxis = list(
            type = 'date',
            tickformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
            #tickformat = "%d %B (%a)<br>%Y"
      ))
```

This yields this new plot.
[image]

All I need is simply daily data and two labels on the x-axis.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the distance of the ticks in Ploty by setting `dtick` for your x- or y-axis in your `layout`.

```
layout(xaxis=list('dtick' = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))
```

Setting it to `60 * 60 * 24 * 1000`, i.e. `86400000` results in a tick every other day.

```
library('plotly')

df <- data.frame(date=c("2020-12-11","2020-12-11","2020-12-12"),
                 typ=c("shirts","sweaters","sweaters"),
                 sold=c(644,3032,407), check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
line_text <- paste0("PORT ID: ",df$typ)

plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~sold, connectgaps = TRUE, mode = "lines+markers", 
        text = line_text) %>% add_lines() %>% layout(showlegend = FALSE, xaxis=list('dtick' = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Maximilian, it's getting better in the sense that it's not showing the hour and time anymore, but it's still showing 5 dates on my end, 3 of which with absolutely no data. Are there any other settings I should check? Thank you

Comment: Maximilian, I found a workaround, that is, I sort the Date column, then convert it to as.character and at that point it works as expected. Many thanks for your help, appreciated